# jQuery if class wasn't clicked for x minutes do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I'm trying to figure out if I can set the time out for clicked button instead of using idle as presented here: [Fire Event When User is Idle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fire-event-when-user-is-idle/)

I would prefer it to be relevant to a link class,
so for example if user didn't click link for over 2 minutes:

**jQuery**

```
if (".linkClass").(idleTime > 2) {
    alert("Hurry Up!");
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()`. When button is clicked, clear the timeout and start it over again. When the timeout executes, show your 'hurry up' `alert`

Comment: Actually yes...wow that was so simple, tnx! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function impatientButton(el, wait) {
  var timeout = 0;

  setTimeout(function(){
     alert('Hurry up!');
  }, wait);

  $(el).click(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  });
}

// Initialise
impatientButton('.selector', 10000);
```

Something like that should do the trick! This will setup a timer to trigger an alert after 10 seconds. If the button is clicked before then, the timer will be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

```
var clickTimeOut=null;

$(".linkClass").on("click",function(){
    clickTimeOut = setTimeout(alertTimeOut, 1000*120);
});

function alertTimeOut()
{
   alert("Hurry Up!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A timer is what you are looking for... 
Maybe like this:

```
var idleTimerId;
$('.linkClass').on('click', function(event){
  idleTimerId = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 5000);
});

// in this example the timer will be initialized when the link is clicked first. 
// Then waits 5000ms to fire. if you want to cancel it - call clearTimeout() 
// with idealTimerId;
```

More Infos about Javascript-Timers in this excellent article:

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ 
or

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
var mt;   

function start_timer() {
    mt = setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hurry Up!");
    }, 12000);
}

function reset_timer() {
    clearTimeout( mt );
    start_timer();
}

$('.linkClass').click(function() {
    reset_timer();
});

start_timer();
```